# Linux 'script' command inside docker not writing to a file as intended

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, docker, logging

I am using linux command 'script' to get terminal output from a docker container into a file. When running the 'script' command, it writes the terminal output to the file after exiting from the 'script' command.

I need the command to work in normal behavior where it writes to the file continuously instead of writing all the terminal output in the end.

Help !

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  job:
    build: .
    environment:
      - "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
    command: script /scripts/terminal.out
    command: python /scripts/init.py
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /scripts
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./scripts .
RUN exit
```

Comment: added the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Comment: irrespective of the dockerfile and docker-compose and the way it is running inside a container, it's giving same response. I tried running the script command in other docker containers as well, but it's writes to the file in the end (after exit command).

Comment: Maybe you need docker run option `--tty`

Comment: how can i give --tty option in docker-compose or dockefile @mviereck

Comment: I am not familar with compose syntax. Looking at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir you need to add line `tty: true` to your compose file. (In dockerfile this is not possible at all.)

Comment: tried a simple ubuntu image --tty option and this approach didn't work.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this, for instance you can't have two `command` steps in your compose file, and I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `RUN exit`. Can you go a bit higher level and tell us the use case you're working on?

Comment: Probably the command should be in one line: `command: script -c 'python /scripts/init.py'  /scripts/terminal.out`

Comment: -c option also doesn't work, its writing to the file after exit command @mviereck

Comment: How do you know? Are you looking at the file and seeing that it contains everything you want in the image after the last `RUN` step, but not in the image immediately before it? (Make sure to actually examine the containers before saying "yes", or otherwise describe why you believe the problem is delayed writes and not missing writes)

Comment: This sounds like either you want to run the container as a foreground process and capture its output (`docker run ... > file`), or run the container in the background and use `docker logs` to see its output.

Comment: @johnharris85 I am running cron jobs in the container. Also I want to show logs/output from these containers to be written to a .html file to display the logs/output of each job on browser via sharing the logs/output with a nginx web server.

Comment: I used PYTHONBUFFERED=1 in my docker-compose to write all the output of python program in docker logs and that is being written to a shared volume in nginx container

Answer (score 0):

Instead of script, I did set a env variable inside python container in docker-compose.yml - PYTHONBUFFERED=1.
And then docker logs -f  will display all the logs and output of the python script as well. So that gives all the terminal output in the file :)